# jQuery (event.which), mousedown Browser Compatibility

Tags: jquery

I've seen very similar questions relative to this, but those only cover keypress events and not mouse clicks the way I'm doing it.

Basically I'm trying to determine if a user is clicking the left or right mouse button. My code:

```
$(".class_name").mousedown(function () {

    switch (event.which) {
        case 1: //leftclick
            //...
            break;
        case 3: //rightclick
            //...
            break;
    }
});
```

This works as intended in Safari but not IE or Firefox. IE & FF act as if nothing happened, while Safari executes the code for that particular click. jQuery is typically good about cross-browser compatibility so I'm guessing I need to format the code differently, but not sure how exactly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried logging the event and examining it? http://jsfiddle.net/bGLcm/1/

Comment: @errieman: Your example is different than his.

Comment: @Rocket: It is an example for him so he can solve it himself. Which might help him solve future problems too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the [*global* `window.event`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html#link3) object, and not jQuery's event object.  `window.event` only works in some browsers, and it is not a W3C standard.

jQuery normalizes the event object so it's the same in all browsers.  The event handler is passed that jQuery event object as a parameter.  You should be using that.

```
$(".class_name").mousedown(function (e) {

    switch (e.which) {
        case 1: //leftclick
            //...
            break;
        case 3: //rightclick
            //...
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten to put the event variable in the function call.

```
$(".class_name").mousedown(function (/*HERE*/event) {

switch (event.which) {
    case 1: //leftclick
        //...
        break;
    case 3: //rightclick
        //...
        break;
 }
});
```